# how to translate sign under appbar buttom

Tags: localization, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Hello I want to localize text below standard AddAppBarButton

```
<Style x:Key="AddAppBarButtonStyle" TargetType="ButtonBase" BasedOn="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="AddAppBarButton"/>
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="Add"/>
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="&#xE109;"/>
</Style>
```

I've tried in Resource filead add something like

```
ButtonId.AutomationProperties.Name = value
```

But it doesn not work. I get errors when app starts. How can I trasnlate this property ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not [put the translation strings in resource files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965329.aspx) and let XAML parser do the work?

You need to create a folder in your project matching the locale name and put a resw file inside it, e.g `sl-SI\Resources.resw`.

Add `x:Uid` attribute to XAML elements to name them:

```
<Button x:Uid="AppBarButton" Style="{StaticResource AddAppBarButtonStyle}" />
```

Now just name the resource strings appropriately so that the XAML parser will find them. The pattern is `UidName.PropertyName`, e.g. `Button.Content`. In the case of AppBar buttons the syntax is a little more complex because of attached properties:

```
AppBarButton.[using:Windows.UI.Xaml.Automation]AutomationProperties.Name
```

Comment: As I wrote. I'm doing this. I have the Resources.resw file but I didn't know the syntax for AutomationProperties. I'll check it asap and let you know

Comment: This more complex syntax is what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could try AutomationProperties.SetName(ButtonId, value);