# Display special characters located in a .resx file

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using a symbol font in my WPF project (Segoe UI Symbol) to display icons without having to deal with images. I can display icons with the following XAML code :

```
<customControlsc:CircularButton Header="&#xe109;"
                                FontFamily="{StaticResource Symbols}" />
```

[image: result of the code above]

This code works just fine, but I have to look for the icon code ('U+E109') everytime I want to add an icon, which is not really convenient.

So I thought, why not putting all the symbols codes I need in a resource file? I already have a resource file to manage languages in my application, so I simply added the following lines :

[image: .resx file]

And now I use the following XAML code :

```
<cc:CircularButton Header="{Binding Strings.Symbol_Add, Source={StaticResource LangManager}}"
                   FontFamily="{StaticResource Symbols}" />
```

However, it does not work, I obtain the following result :

[image: weird result]

I don't know why, but WPF seem to interpret the special character in my .resx file as a string, whereas it interprets it properly when the symbol code is directly put into my XAML file...

---

Okay, now I get it.

In code, when you use a special character sequence, such as "&# xe109;" in WPF or "\ue109" in C#, you are actually writing a single character with the hex code 'E109'.

In .resx file, the special character sequence "" is saved as plain text, not as a single character, since .resx don't depend of the language you are using. The simplest way I found to make it work was to save the hex unicode identifier of the special char I wanted to use (that is to say, 0xE109), and then convert it to a character.

I simply used a converter :

```
public class CodeToIconConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var str = (string)value; // str = "E109"

        // create a char from the hex number "E109"
        return (char)int.Parse(str, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    }
    // ...
```

XAML:

```
<cc:CircularButton Header="{Binding Strings.Symbol_Add, Source={StaticResource LangManager, Converter={StaticResource CodeToIconConverter}}"
                   FontFamily="{StaticResource Symbols}" />
```

Comment: Yes, the &#x prefix is Chinese curse that should only appear in XML.  Not in the resource designer, it is just a plain string now.  Simplest way I can think of is to use Charmap.exe, select Segoe UI Symbol and copy/paste the character into the Value column.

Comment: You can have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572273/how-to-translate-sign-under-appbar-buttom

Comment: It's weird, the character map doesn't display all the symbols available in Segoe UI Symbols [link](http://i.imgur.com/RsIJTvJ.png) I tried to copy some of the few characters (such as U+E010) into my .resx file, it works. Too bad I can't see all the characters...

Comment: It might be easiest to edit the resource file in a text editor, since it is XML behind the scenes, and so at that level the `&#x` will work.